# Remove percent sign after System.out.print();

Tags: java

I have statements like the following throughout my program:

```
System.out.print(root.key + " ");
```

For some reason every time these print together there exist a percentage sign at the end.

```
4 5 6 7 %
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: what's the value of `root.key`?

Comment: root is referring to the root of a subtree within a Binary Search Tree. root.key in this instance is an int. None of the values contain a percentage sign.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? It's impossible to find the cause from just a single line of code.

Comment: `"...every time these print together..."` -- Can you show us a sample sequence of print statements? While the statement you showed us has no percent sign, you haven't showed us all of the print statements.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tailing space in your log output?
No matter what type and value `root.key` is, your statement will print space in last position.
If you do not have space, then the % sign comes not from System.out.print you have provided, but from some other `System.out.print` that is executed further.

Jsut debug your code- you will see every time your `System.out.print(root.key + " ");` is executed and you will be able to confirm values of `root.key`. I guess that if you debug further, you will find next statement that does `System.out.print("%")`.